# pass to 2 different php pages selected dropdown value. Not javascript

Tags: php, html

I am looking for only PHP. NOT javaScript.

I have a drop down which has 1 of the 15 week. If i chooses any value from that drop down it should go to selected page and say..

Welcome you have selected week #

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['attendance'])) {
   header('Location:attendance_page.php');
} else if (isset($_POST['handout'])) {
   header('Location:handout_page.php');
} else if (isset($_POST['assignment'])) {
   header('Location:assignment_page.php');
}
?> 
<form action="#" method="post"  >
<p>Welcome Professor Mr.XYZ !</p><br/><br/>
<select name="sweek">
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=15;$i++)<!--i am populating dropdown with 15 weeks-->
    {
        echo "<option value='Week$i'> Week $i</option>";
    }
?>
</select><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="attendance" value="Attendance" />
<input type="submit" name="handout" value="Handout" />
<input type="submit" name="assignment" value="Assignment" />
</form>
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: Not possible with just php or html, you could do it if you made the user click a submit button though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post to two differenet pages you need to post to one and then redirect to the other. But you can't redirect with `post` data in PHP.

You'd need to use `get` instead of `post`. To transform post to get you can do:

```
$get = http_build_query($_POST) . "\n";
header('Location: otherpage?' . $get);
```